# How to sync data between mysql and android app for offline mode using

Tags: android, mysql

I'm not professional in android and i'm developing app which i want it to work in offline mode and online mode

my server is mysql and contain data i want in offline mode user can see data which is synchronized when app was online

after long search i found `coughbase`
but i don't know if it can help me or not 
someone suggest me to use `sqlite` but i know sqlite can't save big data 
i want to do this in fast way can anyone guide me what i should do ? and if examples is exists it will be good .. sorry for bad English

Comment: you need to save retrieved data in local database and then preview data from local database

Comment: u mean sqlite ? even my data is big ?

Comment: you can clear data base if user back to online statue so there is no big data !

Comment: yes its not a good idea to keep big data on the user device

Comment: no i don't want to clear data .. i want to load old and recent data

Comment: You should just keep on user device some portions of data, for example the latest data otherwise if you try always to get all the data from original database you can fill up the space on user's device pretty fast, of course depending on the data ...

Comment: ok so if i want to display latest data only i should use preferences or what ? have any example ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use preferences, when the app is online synchronize your data via web services (json) and save the on the user's phone or tablet via preferences, you can store what ever you like, it's not like a data base, you can store objects in a way it's like cookies on the browser.
your data will be saved as xml and accessed as objects and every class you wanna synchronize must implement Serializable interface.

Comment: can u provide my with samples plz ? ^_^

Comment: it isn't bad to save big data ?

Comment: if you save a big amount of data you have to consider phones with low storage capacity,

Comment: it's good to save data but not all of it like the messenger app even offline you can find same of your old messages but not all of them because this will be bad and it may make your app slow

Comment: some good links http://moonlightbox.logdown.com/posts/2015/04/14/android-store-object-in-shared-preferences    //     https://github.com/fsilvestremorais/android-complex-preferences

Comment: ok so if i want to display latest data only i should use preferences or what ?

Comment: For a small amount of data sqlite is the best option